# Default folder routes using Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, routes

I'm starting a new webforms project using Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls but want to be able to set a default route for a folder. I have a folder called news which contains news.aspx and newsitem.aspx. I'd like to be able to route as follows:

```
http://sitename/news - Routes to ~/news/news.aspx
http://sitename/news/news - Routes to ~/news/news.aspx
http://sitename/news/newsitem - Routes to ~/news/newsitem.aspx
```

The second and third routes work using the code below but not `http://sitename/news`

```
 public static class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);

        routes.MapPageRoute("NewsDefault", "news", "~/news/news.aspx");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Found Solution**

Needed to add `routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;`

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
            settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
            routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
            routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;

            routes.MapPageRoute("NewsDefault", "news", "~/news/news.aspx");
        }
```