# URL Routing .Net 4.5 Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have a webforms app that I would like to add some routing in so when a user types in www.mySite.com/Brd it will take them to a specific page. I can get this to work if I put an argument in, however I don't want any. Here is what I have in my application start method

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  RegisterRoute(System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes);
}

void RegisterRoute(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes)
{
  routes.MapPageRoute("Route1", "Rep", "~/SalesRep/SalesRepHome.aspx");
  routes.MapPageRoute("Route2", "Brd", "~/Board/BrdLogin.aspx");


}
```

The route for the Brd takes me to www.mysite.com/BrdLogin.aspx without the subdirectory and the Rep route does nothing. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you really mean WinForms? Or do you mean WebForms?

Comment: Wow.... long day, edited it to fix

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try adding this line to your RegisterRoutes method...

```
routes.EnableFriendlyUrls();
```

Make sure you're also referencing the `Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls` assembly

Also, try putting a forward slash after Rep and Brd e.g.

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Route1", "Rep/", "~/SalesRep/SalesRepHome.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("Route2", "Brd/", "~/Board/BrdLogin.aspx");
```

Comment: Tried that and it gives me the resource not found error. It does take the .aspx off my pages. any other suggestions?

Comment: I didn't call the registerRoutes method, once I did the application did the same thing it was doing before. the Brd route takes me to /BrdLogin.aspx and Rep does nothing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24261737/default-folder-routes-using-microsoft-aspnet-friendlyurls-webforms this seemed to get things working, going to mark yours as the answer as it pointed me in the right direction.